# No EventLogAppender in Log4Net 2.0.14

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to configure an EventLogAppender in a .Net 6.0 console app, I'm using Log4Net 2.0.14 and I getting the following Exception...

```
 log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [EventLogAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=2.0.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [EventLogAppender] not found.
```

This is my appender:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
        <applicationName value="Application" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the official [EventLogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#eventlogappender) doc:

> Please note that this appender is not natively available in log4net for dotnet standard, as it would bring in windows dependencies for non-windows consumers. Please see https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.appenders.netcore for an alternative if you still require EventLog logging for netstandard targets

So use the Nuget package "Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore".

The appender declaration is slightly different:

```
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore.EventLogAppender,Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore">
```